# No data send with socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have to send data using socket.io.when a user enter his login and a password,he will be redirect to index.ejs and the username will be send to the server.
route.js (I mentioned only the part of the script not the hole script to show that when the login and password are correct a user get an index page and the userobject send to the index):

```
    var index = function(req, res, next) {
   if(!req.isAuthenticated()) {
      res.redirect('/signin');
   } else {

      var user = req.user;

      if(user !== undefined) {
         user = user.toJSON();
      }
      res.render('index', {title: 'Home', user: user});
   }
};
```

app.js:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

socket.on("new_user",function(user1){
console.log("a new user is connected",user1);
var current_date=new Date();
var date=current_date.toString();
ex.user_connect(user1,date);
});
});
```

index.ejs:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width ,initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">HomePage</a>
                </div>
            <div>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#"><%= user.username%></a></li>
                <li><a href="/signout"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Sign out</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6">
<div class="container">
  <h2>Led1</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" id="led1" align="center">check it</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="model_led1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header" style="padding:35px 50px;">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" id="close">&times;</button>
          <h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span> Settings</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" style="padding:40px 50px;">
          <form role="form">

            <img src="style/images/led.png" id="led" class="img-responsive"/>
              <button  type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block" id="led1_activ"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> Activate</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block" id="led1_desactiv"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> Desactivate</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal" id="cancel_button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Cancel</button>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
</div>

<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
    var user1 =  user.username;
    socket.emit('new_user',user1);

</script>
```

NB:I got the username on the navbar but I don't get it on the server console.

Comment: And, what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ejs render all template variables  in server and then return plain html to the client , so

Inside your script , do you have variable global **user** initialized? :

```
var user1 = user.username // var user = {username:"foo":} ,something like that before.
```

If you trying to get user from template variable you could try:

```
var user1= "<%= user.username%>";
```

This will render <%= user.username%> inside script tag before send to the client ( browser)